# JQuery Chosen plugin - clear 'current_value' property

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-chosen

I am using the jquery chosen plugin, but am unable to access one of the properties which I need to clear, namely 'current_value' which is used to store the last selected value. I have a particular use case where I would like to clear this field. I have added a reset method to the plugin, but I am not able to get a reference to the instance of the chosen object to invoke the new method. I can see this field and change it in firebug, but I can't work out how to call it.

Comment: Chosen updates the underlying select element, so you should be able to clear the value there and call "liszt:updated" to trigger. That's the traditional way at least; what's your use case?